# How much the angular api is safe we connect with backend?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my angular 5.0 application, I use the rest api. all works fine. the doubt about this service is, I can able to see the payload on the netwrok tab of chrome browser. as well there is a token authentication exist.

now in case a person takes the both information and edits the payload which is not connected with my app, he can able to post through `postman`.

in this case how the way my api are safety here?
or what i missing to implement in my `api` data transactions?

any one help me to understand or correct me what i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that this link will help you with your question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS